# How to get ROW_NUM from dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have this piece of code :

```
DO
$$
DECLARE v_RowCountInt  Int;
BEGIN
    execute ('insert into vcc.toto select * from vcc.segment s limit 50 
              on conflict (id_segment,pds) do update 
              set id_segment = excluded.id_segment
                  ,pds = excluded.pds');

    GET DIAGNOSTICS v_RowCountInt = ROW_COUNT;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Returned % rows', v_RowCountInt;
END;
$$
```

The RAISE NOTICE return 50 rows which is what i want.

But if i add this to my code

```
DO
$$
DECLARE v_RowCountInt  Int;
DECLARE query_plan varchar;
BEGIN
    execute ('explain (analyze, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, format json) 
              insert into vcc.toto select * from vcc.segment s limit 50 
              on conflict (id_segment,pds) do update 
              set id_segment = excluded.id_segment
                  ,pds = excluded.pds')
              into query_plan;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS v_RowCountInt = ROW_COUNT;

    RAISE NOTICE 'Returned % rows', v_RowCountInt;
END;
$$
```

This RAISE 1 row only (because of into query_plan i think)

How can i get 50 rows instead while keeping the "INTO query_plan" variable ?

Thanks

Comment: Why the dynamic SQL? That seems pretty useless.

Comment: because the exemple is just an exemple. In my code i need to use dynamic query because of other parameters. I just made my exemple easyer to understand :)

Comment: The cause is not `INTO query_plan` but `explain(analyse, ...)` which returns one row. You should append your `execute('insert into ... ')` statement after `execute('explain( ...`

Comment: Thanks @Edouard ! I manage to get it work with your advice.